# How to install and use php-pushwoosh on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Linux OS with/without using Composer?

Tags: php, ubuntu, push-notification, composer-php, pushwoosh

I want to install and use **php-pushwoosh** on my system running on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Linux OS.

For it I went to the link [php-pushwoosh website](http://gomoob.github.io/php-pushwoosh/). There I come to know about I can install **php-pushwoosh** by using Composer:

> The easiest way to install the library is to use Composer and define the following dependency inside your composer.json file.

But I've no idea about Composer and how to install any software using Composer. My ultimate goal is to install **php-pushwoosh** on my machine and execute the code. Be it install by Composer or not, it doesn't matter so much to me.

If you could explain some working code example of **php-pushwoosh** to send push-notification to iPhone that would be even great.

Comment: The passage you quoted contains a link (on the original page) to [getcomposer.org](https://getcomposer.org/). You should be able to get all related information from there.

Comment: @Rangad:I gone to the link, created the directory on my machine, open the terminal and run the command 'curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php' in to the newly created directory, composer got installed successfully message came, but what next? How to install php-pushwoosh? My main concern is still unanswered. Please help me.

Comment: Hi, an issue has been create here https://github.com/gomoob/php-pushwoosh/issues/23, perhaps it can help using the library without composer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Composer is a tool for dependency management in PHP. It allows you to declare the dependent libraries your project needs and it will install them in your project for you.

If you are a PHP developer by profession I really recommend getting into composer, you will love this piece of software.

It's not so complicated as it looks at first glance, just read [Composer's introduction](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md) and you should be able to install composer and require any packages.

#### Start a new project

1. Create a new folder `my-project-name/`

#### Following the [composer project install guide](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md)

1. Create a new file `my-project-name/composer.json`
2. Look at the [`php-pushwoosh` install guide](http://gomoob.github.io/php-pushwoosh/) and copy the require section into your `composer.json` file:

```json
{
    "require": {
        "gomoob/php-pushwoosh": "~1.0"
    }
}
```

3. Move into your project folder (terminal/command line) `cd my-project-name`
4. Run `composer install`
5. wait ...
6. start a new `php-file` and reqire `require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';`
7. start programming

Comment: I gone to the link, created the directory on my machine, open the terminal and run the command 'curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php' in to the newly created directory, composer got installed successfully message came, but what next? How to install php-pushwoosh? My main concern is still unanswered. Please help me.

Comment: Really? All you need is in described in the section [declaring dependencies](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#declaring-dependencies). And [basic usage](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md). In short: Create a folder with a `composer.json` require your `php-pushwoosh` and run `composer install` in that folder.

Comment: :Sorry I didn't get you. Can you please post next steps as your answer? It would be of great help to me.

Comment: Edited the answer. If you don't get it now, i can't help anymore. The composer manual is your new best friend. I again recommend to have a deeper look into composer. As a php developer it's definitely worth that time and you will love it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help till now. It worked perfect as you said. You made the thing I though impossible the possible. Just last question man, where should I store this PHP file? I mean where in the project directory? Pleas help me.

Comment: This is up to you, as this is your projects start point now. You can call it `index.php` and run it from cli or through a webserver. Depends on the project you are building now.

Comment: `my-project-name/index.php` for example

Comment: Thanks once again for your helping hand.